# Jquery : How do I get the current id of the element I have clicked on and change it’s name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drag n drop website builder which uses html blocks, each with an id that is set. Once the blocks are dropped onto the canvas, I need to create a nav menu linking to the ids of each block. How do I get the current id of the block I have clicked on and change it’s name?

Below is what I have tried,but it has a few problems :

1. It doesn’t show the name of the block
2. It only accepts integers (gives NaN when I type in text)
3. It changes the ids of all blocks on the canvas, instead of just changing the id of the block I have clicked on

.

**Php Page (index.php)**

```
  <div class="setting opt">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a class="icons" data-toggle="dropdown"  href="#settings"></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
        <li><a href="#" id="blockName" tabindex="-1">Edit Block Name</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
<section class="builder_block" id="header_2"></section>
<section class="builder_block" id="content_5"></section>
<section class="builder_block" id="footer_9"></section>
```

**Jquery Page (editor.js)**

```
$(document).on("click", "#blockName", function(e) {
e.preventDefault(),toastr.info("Block Renamed.");
    var bname = prompt("Please enter your new block name");
    var myblockName = $("section.builder_block").attr("id", +bname);
 });
```

Comment: $(this).attr("id", bname);

Comment: I am not really sure what you want to do. If I click on the button, which block should it change? What should it change? Just the ID, or title or what? What gets typed in?

Answer (score 0):

In jquery, you can use:

```
$(this).attr('id', [new-value]);
```

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('div[id^="block-"]').click(function(){
        $(this).attr('id','new-' + $(this).attr('id'));
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace('block','new-block'));
    });

});
```

```css
div {
display: inline-block;
margin: 6px;
padding: 6px;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="block-1">My <em>id</em> is <strong>block-1</strong></div>
<div id="block-2">My <em>id</em> is <strong>block-2</strong></div>
<div id="block-3">My <em>id</em> is <strong>block-3</strong></div>
```

Click on each box in the example to retrieve the `id` of the `div` and replace it with a new updated `id`.

---

Here is the native javascript version, so you can compare and contrast with the jQuery above:

```js
var blocks = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="block"]');

function updateId() {
var id = this.id;
id = id.replace('block','new-block');
this.id = id;

var html = this.innerHTML;
html = html.replace('block','new-block');
this.innerHTML = html;
}

for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
    blocks[i].addEventListener('click',updateId,false);
}
```

```css
div {
display: inline-block;
margin: 6px;
padding: 6px;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div id="block-1">My <em>id</em> is <strong>block-1</strong></div>
<div id="block-2">My <em>id</em> is <strong>block-2</strong></div>
<div id="block-3">My <em>id</em> is <strong>block-3</strong></div>
```